# ColorBox jQuery Editing

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using the jQuery plugin ColorBox.

I want to have it styled like facebook.

So the Photo will be on the left, and description, comments on the right.

I am not good with javascript, i'm asking if someone can take a look at the code and give me an advice on how to edit the code..

Basically, i need to replace the current div that is displaying the image with 2 DIVs with `float:left`.

On the first div will be loaded the image, and on the second the description and some custom html.

I'm using the fixed width/height theme.

I have taked a look, but as i said before i'm not good with javascript, and i don't know where to edit.

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to edit the source of the plugin

change the css for cboxTitle & cboxLoadedContent (float:left, set some width)

to add custom content (more than the title property of the a tag) you'll have to use onLoad or onOpen callback

```
$("#inline").colorbox({
       onOpen : function() {
            //apend your content to cboxTitle
          }
       });
```

Comment: i've already tried to edit the css, but it is not working. Manually setting the width for cboxLoadedContent is not working. The width it's always at 100% of the ColorBox.

Comment: then show some code -in your question you made a mistake somewhere

Comment: I tried some more, but by only editing the css the result it's not really good. I need to edit the javascript

Comment: no you don't, use event callback & learn css; &use firebug to view colorbox html structure

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler approach would be top use ColorBox with its iFrame option. I have done this such that the plugin opens an entirely new HTML page which can be styled anyway you like. In this way, you are basically using ColorBox as a windowing manager.
Good luck!

Comment: Yes this will be an easy solution.. But i like colorbox with images, because it's a lot faster to load them since it has preloading.
I don't know if it's possible to preload also the iframe content.